# ios - a single static header that changes as you scroll

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, sectionheader

I've been searching a ton and can not seem to find an answer...

I have a tableView which scrolls all the days of all the months. And I have a titleForHeaderInSection: and viewForHeaderInSection: which displays a section header at the top of each month-section which replaces appropriately at the top, cool.   But how can I create a single header where the titleLabel changes to the proper month as I scroll (in other words, Not have multiple section headers, just one)?

I can't tell whether this should be setup as "one (big) section with a header that changes" or "a headerView that changes", or whatever...  Any examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a static view and place it above your tableView.  Then you can use the `visibleCells` property to determine which cells are visible.  When those cells change to the cells of a new section you can update the static view that is above the `UITableView`.

Once you are the `delegate` of the `UITableView` you are also the `delegate` of the `UIScrollView` it is built on.

So you can catch the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate call and update your header there.

So to lay it out:

1.) Create a Header View above your `UITableView`

2.) Become the `delegate` of the `UITableView`

3.) Implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to detect scrolls

4.) Inside the `scrollViewDidScroll` method use the `visibleCells` property of the `UITableView` to determine which cells are being shown and to update your header view appropriately.

I've never done anything like this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

EDIT: As Husker Jeff pointed out.  It is probably easier to use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` to determine what is on screen.  You can then use that fairly easily to determine which section/sections are being displayed.  Thanks Jeff!

Comment: Justin beat me by about a minute and said almost everything I was going to say.  The only thing I'd add is that you could use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` instead of `visibleCells`--it might save you a step in getting to the underlying data.

Comment: Excellent Addition Husker, that would be a bit easier, especially if he is changing the header by section.